# IE leaks memory for dynamically generated javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Recently I have to execute script retrieved thru Ajax from web server periodically. I do it by first creating a Script tag and assign the text attribute to run the script. Then, I dispose the script tag just to find out that memory keep increasing on every creation in IE 7. The following HTML illustrate the problem:

```
<html>
<body>
<span id='m_garbageBin'></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonClicked()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            var sc = document.createElement("script");
            sc.text = "var x=1;";
            document.body.appendChild(sc);
            m_garbageBin.appendChild(sc);
            m_garbageBin.innerHTML = '';
        }
    }
</script>
<script id='m_dynamicScript' type="text/javascript">
</script>
    <input type='button' value='Click me!' onclick='buttonClicked();'/>
</body>
```

The script isn't doing anything at all and still memory keep increasing on every click on the button in IE but not in Firefox (by using .innerHTML instead of .text). The fact that I have to retrieve the script to execute periodically cannot be changed. Anybody knows what I can do to avoid the memory increase in IE?

Comment: Where is `m_garbageBin` defined?  Also, of course memory usage is increasing, you're creating 100000 elements every time you run the function.

Comment: @Luke: the above is illustrative of the problem, rather than being Conrad's original script (presumably, the AJAX portion works fine).

Comment: i am sorry if I haven't stated my question clear enough but as Luke points out, the above is only an illustration of my problem. I am fully aware that it isn't ajax.
To Justin, the fact that I have move the script element into a dedicated element and clear the html of that element should have made IE released the memory... I hoped.

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove the `script` elements just after they are appended, something like this may help:

```
function buttonClicked() {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.text = "var x=1;";
        head.appendChild(script);
        head.removeChild(script);
    }
}
```

That's the way some modern libraries, like jQuery [make it](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L467).

See also:

- [Global Scope Evaluation and DOM Investigation](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2007/08/global-scope-evaluation-and-dom.html)

Comment: As far as I know, IE has problem regarding the removeChild function that it doesn't actually release the memory until the page is unloaded even an element is removed using that call. Some refer that as "psuedo-leak": http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg05231.html

Answer (score 0):

try `delete sc;` when after setting the `innerHTML` to `''`.

Comment: The `delete` statement will actually fail (it will return false, and nothing will be deleted), because the variable instantiation made in the *"Function Code"* execution context, sets the variables with the `{ DontDelete }` property attribute, more info: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.2.3